# QT5 SVG qt.svg: link #glyph2-4 is undefined!

Tags: svg, qt5

В общем, мне нужно отобразить график который я получаю с rrdtool в формате svg. Хорошо, отдаю график по http протоколу с content-type=svg/xml, в браузере всё отлично. Соответственно в qt есть решение QSvgWidget, я его использую, делаю get запрос по http к серверу. График отображается, но не полностью. На нём нету шрифта, цифр, в общем всё то, что представляет текстовую инфу.

Сам qt в консоли орет это:

```
qt.svg: link #glyph1-11 is undefined!
qt.svg: link #glyph1-9 is undefined!
qt.svg: link #glyph1-12 is undefined!
qt.svg: link #glyph1-9 is undefined!
qt.svg: link #glyph1-13 is undefined!
qt.svg: link #glyph1-11 is undefined!
qt.svg: link #glyph1-3 is undefined!
qt.svg: link #glyph1-11 is undefined!
qt.svg: link #glyph2-1 is undefined!
qt.svg: link #glyph2-1 is undefined!
qt.svg: link #glyph2-2 is undefined!
qt.svg: link #glyph2-3 is undefined!
qt.svg: link #glyph2-4 is undefined!
qt.svg: link #glyph2-4 is undefined!
qt.svg: link #glyph2-5 is undefined!
qt.svg: link #glyph2-6 is undefined!
qt.svg: link #glyph2-7 is undefined!
qt.svg: link #glyph2-6 is undefined!
qt.svg: link #glyph2-3 is undefined!
```

Comment: А сами элементы в теле SVG с `id="glyph2-4"` и прочие присутствуют или подразумевается, что подгружаются по ссылке? Попробуйте открыть SVG файл векторном редакторе, там будут отображаться ваши буквы?

Comment: Да, буквы отображаются. Открыл в incscape

Comment: Так эти элементы присутствуют или нет? Ссылки на их использование присутствуют явно или нет? Может это вроде переменных окружения, которые есть по умолчанию в браузере исходя из системных шрифтов или шрифтов по умолчанию, а в QT этих "по умолчанию" нет и надо прописывать явно.

Answer (score 0):

Сам SVG бы посмотреть...

Ну и опять же, попробуйте рендерить ваш SVG как это показано в примерах QT:
https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtsvg-svgviewer-example.html

Comment: По этому примеру и делал :(

Comment: скиньте ссылку на svg. интересно посмотреть